# mysql join and insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a view using left join to see the number of duplicate ip.

In this view

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    b.id,
    COUNT (b.id),
    a.ip
FROM
    `VIEW` AS a
LEFT JOIN
    `VIEW` AS b on a.ip = b.ip
WHERE
    a.id = 298
GROUP BY
    b.id;
```

When i execute this query, i get the data i want for one id.

[image: first query execute result]

However, if i check the number of duplicate ip's in the whole id

and execute the following query to store it in the table.

```
INSERT
INTO
    TABLE
SELECT
    a.id,
    b.id,
    COUNT (b.id),
    a.ip
FROM
    `VIEW` AS a
LEFT JOIN
    `VIEW` AS a.ip = b.ip
WHERE
    a.id IN
             (
             SELECT DISTINCT
                 id
             FROM
                 `VIEW`)
GROUP BY
    b.id;
```

Other values come out.

[image: second query execute result]

The first query statement works fine and the second query statement shows an invalid value.

How can I use the second query statement to get the result of the first query statement?

Comment: `AS a.ip = b.ip` is a syntax error, it should be `ON a.ip = b.ip`

Comment: You have no ON clause. Confused.

Comment: Just an aside - why did you call your view 'view', try and come up with more descriptive names.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause in the second query is useless, it's just selecting all the ids.

Comment: @NigelRen It's obviously just an example, like calling his table `TABLE`.

Comment: I did not check that syntax error part. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY a.id, b.id` so that you get a separate count for each `a.id` that you join with.

There's also no reason to use `LEFT JOIN` here. Since you're joining the view with itself, there will always be a matching row. Just use a normal `INNER JOIN`.

The `WHERE` clause is totally ineffective. How can the id *not* be in the list of distinct id's from the same view? Get rid of that clause.

You also have a syntax error:

```
JOIN `VIEW` AS a.ip = b.ip
```

should be:

```
JOIN `VIEW` AS b ON a.ip = b.ip
```

The correct query should be:

```
INSERT
INTO
    TABLE
SELECT
    a.id,
    b.id,
    COUNT(*),
    a.ip
FROM
    `VIEW` AS a
JOIN
    `VIEW` AS b ON a.ip = b.ip

GROUP BY
    a.id, b.id;
```

Comment: I did not check that syntax error part. I'm sorry.
thanks to you, i can solve problem